# hdpi-density phone takes dimen values from xhdpi folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a couple of folders for normal-bucket devices: values-xhdpi, values. Somehow Samsung i9001(hdpi device) grabs dimen values from values-xhdpi, while I suppose him to take it from the default(values) folder.

What makes him do it and how to go about this issue?

**UPD**
atm i just copied values folder into values-hdpi

Comment: Samsung modifications? Is it possible to root the device and flash with eg. Cyanogen to check it?

Comment: what exactly? how does it relate to the question? p.s. I dont have Cyanogen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Somehow Samsung i9001(hdpi device) grabs dimen values from values-xhdpi, while I suppose him to take it from the default(values) folder.

For density resource set qualifiers, Android will choose the nearest density, if there is no exact match. I had originally thought that this was just for drawables, but it is for all resource types. I recently wrote [a blog post on this topic](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/06/fun-with-density-resource-set-qualifiers.html).

Comment: okay, thanks - do you think copying values folder into values-hdpi is a fine solution?

Comment: @midnight: Either that, or you may be able to use resource aliases. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources